# Trying to get and element's css and assert that it's true, I keep getting errors

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I want to verify the CSS on the navigation bar of a website*, mainly the color and the position.  Here is the relevant HTML:

```html
<div id="MainNavigationMenu" class="header-menu">
```

My method for acquiring the navigation CSS is the following:

```
public string getLandingColor(){
    IWebElement getLink = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("header-menu"));

    //checking the color = #767676
    string NavigationMenu = getLink.GetCssValue("color");

    return NavigationMenu;
}
```

My test is:

```
[Test, Description("Testing Landing Page and Asserting Format Check")]
public void LandingPageVerificiation() {
        Assert.AreSame("#767676", getLandingColor());       
}
```

NUnit displays the following exception:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Unable to find element with class name == header-menu
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
at UnitTestProject1.Browser_Landing.getLandingColor() in c:\Users\erikag\Desktop\AutomationTests\VS_NetSeleniumTest\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1\Browser_Landing.cs:line 53
at UnitTestProject1.ServiceConsoleTest.LandingPageVerificiation() in c:\Users\erikag\Desktop\AutomationTests\VS_NetSeleniumTest\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1\TestSuite_LandLog.cs:line 39
```

My browser opens, so I know my test setup and teardown are working.

How do I properly retrieve this element in the HTML using its class name and assert that the CSS Value color is = to #767676

**The website is www.smartdrive.net and the HTML sample came directly from it*

Comment: Post the exception being thrown, with call stack.

Comment: Thanks Patrick! I'm new to this so I'm learning the best way to post and navigate.  I appreciate the assist!

Comment: I tried to make your question easier to read/understand.  Hope that helps

Comment: Patrick, no it makes a lot more sense how you laid it out! thank you again.

Comment: After staring for hours/day at this and researching it looks like IE11 has issues with Selenium WebDriver, however I have to use IE11 for my testing.  Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

To make Webdriver work with IE11 there's more than noted on the google forums that I have found:

Make IE11 work; webdriver

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

and

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQFwa8OgxLM

regedit fixes

1. For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Please note that the FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.  **taken from the IE webdriver help docs**
2. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\FeatureControl\FEATURE_DISABLE_INTERANL_SECURITY_MANAGER

   - make sure iexplore.exe dword = 1
3. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_DISABLE_INTERANL_SECURITY_MANAGER

   - make sure iexplore.exe dword = 1
4. Internet Options > Security, check Enable Protected Mode & Advanced > Security > Uncheck Enable Enhanced Protected Mode